# Extract name between a word and comma from text with regex

Tags: python, regex, text, extract

I have a thousands .txt files with a large text. I want to extract some information from these files, like some names, numbers and dates. There are fields that follow a pattern to be able to extract the information, but others do not. I attach three examples of text.

The problem comes when I need to extract the name of the creator of a company and the name of that company. To extract the name of the creator, there is a pattern in the text. To extract the name of the company no.

The pattern is: start with the words "ante mí:" followed by a name with last names and ending in comma.

I am using the following code:

```
# Libreria RegEx de Python.
# coding=utf-8
import re

f = open ('/Users/anna/PycharmProjects/extractData/DiarioOficial/aaa1381582.pdf.txt','r')

mensaje = f.read()
mensaje = mensaje.replace("\n","")

print re.findall(r'\s ante mí,+[a-zA-Z]{6-24}\s', mensaje)
```

But I think that the regular expression is wrong.

Can someone help me?

```
CVE 1381582     

|     

Director: Juan Jorge Lazo Rodríguez    

Sitio Web:   

 www.diarioficial.cl    

|     

Mesa Central:   

 +562 2486 3600    

    Email:    

consultas@diarioficial.cl   

Dirección:    

Dr. Torres Boonen N°511, Providencia, Santiago, Chile.       

Este documento ha sido firmado electrónicamente de acuerdo con la ley N°19.799 e incluye sellado de tiempo y firma electrónica  

avanzada. Para verificar la autenticidad de una representación impresa del mismo, ingrese este código en el sitio web www.diarioficial.cl                           

DIARIO OFICIAL    

DE LA REPUBLICA DE CHILE    

Ministerio del Interior y Seguridad Pública      

V    

SECCIÓN       

CONSTITUCIONES, MODIFICACIONES Y DISOLUCIONES DE SOCIEDADES Y COOPERATIVAS                      

Núm. 42.031    

|    

Viernes 13 de Abril de 2018    

|    

Página 1 de 1      

Empresas y Cooperativas    

CVE 1381582        

EXTRACTO     

     

VALERIA RONCHERA FLORES, Notario Titular Décima Notaría Santiago, oficio  

Agustinas 1235, piso 2, CERTIFICO: Por escritura pública hoy ante mí: DANIEL ROLANDO  

CORNEJO GALLARDO, chileno, soltero, factor de comercio, con domicilio en Pueblo Hundido  

sin número, comuna de Rengo, Sexta Región del Libertador Bernardo OHiggins, de paso en  

ésta; constituyó sociedad por acciones denominada AGRÍCOLA Y TRANSPORTES SAN  

DANIEL SpA, nombre de fantasía SAN DANIEL SpA. Objeto Social: Objeto. La Sociedad  

tiene por objeto, la explotación integral del rubro agrícola, ganadero y forestal, por cuenta propia  

o ajena, de predios rústicos propios o ajenos, la importación, exportación, transformación y  

comercialización de productos agrícolas, ganaderos o forestales. En general, la realización de  

toda clase de negocios relacionados con el agro, la producción agropecuaria, frutícola o  

maderera, la compra, venta y exportación de la producción, sea la propia o ajena, servicios de  

embalaje, envasado, packing y de asesoría a productores, y la elaboración de alimentos, de toda  

clase a partir de esa producción; actuar como comisionista o mandatario, para la venta y  

comercio de productos agrarios; realizar inversiones en toda clase de bienes muebles o  

inmuebles, administrarlos y percibir sus frutos o rentas. Asimismo, el transporte de carga y/o  

pasajeros, en vehículos propios, arrendados o en leasing o encomendados a terceros; la  

representación de empresas extranjeras o nacionales de transporte y embalaje; todo lo  

relacionado, de cualquiera forma, en la actualidad o en el futuro, con el flete, traslado y  

transporte de pasajeros o bienes de toda clase y su embalaje, incluyendo las gestiones portuarias  

y aduaneras, en su caso. También el ejercicio de la actividad comercial en sus formas más  

amplias y, en especial, la compraventa, importación, exportación, distribución y  

comercialización de toda clase de bienes, por cuenta propia o ajena, la representación de  

empresas nacionales y extranjeras; y todo otro negocio o actividad conexa con el giro que  

acuerden los socios. Domicilio: Comuna y ciudad de Santiago, Región Metropolitana, sin  

perjuicio de que pueda establecer agencias, sucursales u oficinas en el resto del país o en el  

extranjero. Duración: Indefinida. Capital: $100.000.000.- dividido en 1.000 acciones,  

nominativas, de una sola serie y sin valor nominal; de las cuales el socio constituyente paga 10  

acciones, equivalentes a $1.000.000.-, al contado, en efectivo, que ingresan a caja social, el saldo  

de 990 acciones serán pagadas en un plazo de 3 años a contar de la suscripción del presente  

contrato. Administración: Por accionista constituyente DANIEL ROLANDO CORNEJO  

GALLARDO.- Demás pactos escritura extractada. "Santiago, 9 abril 2018".
```

Comment: `print re.findall(r'ante mí: (.+?), ', mensaje, flags=re.DOTALL)` ?

Comment: Shouldn't `{6-24}` be `{6,24}` ? And if you want to catch both name and surname add space in `[a-zA-Z]` so `[a-zA-Z ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the pattern `([^,]*)` to match everything upto a comma

```
>>> re.findall(r'\sante mí:\s+([^,]*)', mensaje)
['DANIEL ROLANDO  CORNEJO GALLARDO']
```